# error compiling Qt 6.3.0 on Windows with oneAPI icx using c++20

Tags: qt, c++20

The oneAPI icx compiler on windows uses MSVC 14.31.31103
The error is most likely a Qt/oneAPI problem but I’m posting here to see if someone could suggest how to massage the cpp code into compiling based on the error reports.

It compiles using c++17

Here is the Qt bug report. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-103605
The problematic compile output is below

Thanks in advance
Rich

[37/7776] Building CXX object qtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp.obj
FAILED: qtbase/src/gui/CMakeFiles/Gui.dir/itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\bin\icx.exe /nologo /TP -DGui_EXPORTS -DMD4C_USE_UTF8 -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_BUILD_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM_NAME="windows" -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WIN64 -D_WINDLL -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\src\gui\Gui_autogen\include -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\src\gui -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui..\3rdparty\VulkanMemoryAllocator -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0 -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui..\3rdparty\md4c -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-icc -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\src\corelib -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.3.0 -IC:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.3.0\QtCore -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\harfbuzz-ng\include\harfbuzz -IC:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\freetype\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\Library\include" /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /Zi /RTC1 -MDd /W3 -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:wchar_t -bigobj -Qstd=c++20 -QMD -QMT qtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp.obj -QMF qtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp.obj.d /Foqtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp.obj /Fdqtbase\src\gui\CMakeFiles\Gui.dir\ -c C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/qtguiglobal_p.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h:43:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:45:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\type_traits(746,50): error: incomplete type 'QRegularExpression' used in type trait expression
struct is_trivially_destructible : bool_constant<__is_trivially_destructible(_Ty)> {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\type_traits(59,53): note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_trivially_destructible' requested here
struct conjunction<_First, _Rest...> : _Conjunction<_First::value, _First, _Rest...>::type {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\type_traits(64,44): note: in instantiation of template class 'std::conjunctionstd::is_trivially_destructible<QRegularExpression, std::disjunctionstd::_Is_default_allocator<std::allocator<QRegularExpression>, std::_Has_no_alloc_destroystd::allocator<QRegularExpression, QRegularExpression *>>>' requested here
_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool conjunction_v = conjunction<_Traits...>::value;

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(938,20): note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::conjunction_vstd::is_trivially_destructible<QRegularExpression, std::disjunctionstd::_Is_default_allocator<std::allocator<QRegularExpression>, std::_Has_no_alloc_destroystd::allocator<QRegularExpression, QRegularExpression *>>>' requested here
if constexpr (!conjunction_v<is_trivially_destructible<_Ty>, _Uses_default_destroy<_Alloc, _Ty*>>) {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1620,13): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Destroy_rangestd::allocator<QRegularExpression>' requested here
_Destroy_range(_Myfirst, _Mylast, _Al);

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(593,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Tidy' requested here
_Tidy();

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(219,5): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::~vector' requested here
QFileSystemModelPrivate() = default;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,20): note: in defaulted default constructor for 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' first required here
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,7): note: due to 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' being dllexported
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiexports.h(47,26): note: expanded from macro 'Q_GUI_EXPORT'

## define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h(101,36): note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_EXPORT'

## define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstringalgorithms.h(73,7): note: forward declaration of 'QRegularExpression'
class QRegularExpression;

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/qtguiglobal_p.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h:43:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1454:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qtypeinfo.h:43:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\variant:19:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(938,20): error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression
if constexpr (!conjunction_v<is_trivially_destructible<_Ty>, _Uses_default_destroy<_Alloc, _Ty*>>) {
~^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1620,13): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Destroy_rangestd::allocator<QRegularExpression>' requested here
_Destroy_range(_Myfirst, _Mylast, _Al);

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(593,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Tidy' requested here
_Tidy();

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(219,5): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::~vector' requested here
QFileSystemModelPrivate() = default;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,20): note: in defaulted default constructor for 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' first required here
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,7): note: due to 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' being dllexported
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiexports.h(47,26): note: expanded from macro 'Q_GUI_EXPORT'

## define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h(101,36): note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_EXPORT'

## define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/qtguiglobal_p.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h:43:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1454:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qtypeinfo.h:43:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\variant:19:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(939,33): error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'std::_Default_allocator_traitsstd::allocator<QRegularExpression>::value_type' (aka 'QRegularExpression')
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) {

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstringalgorithms.h(73,7): note: forward declaration of 'QRegularExpression'
class QRegularExpression;

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/qtguiglobal_p.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h:43:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1454:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qtypeinfo.h:43:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\variant:19:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(69,57): error: invalid application of 'alignof' to an incomplete type 'QRegularExpression'
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _New_alignof = (_STD max) (alignof(_Ty),
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(827,21): note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::_New_alignof' requested here
_Deallocate<_New_alignof<_Ty>>(_Ptr, sizeof(_Ty) * _Count);

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1621,17): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::allocator::deallocate' requested here
_Al.deallocate(_Myfirst, static_cast<size_type>(_Myend - _Myfirst));

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(593,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Tidy' requested here
_Tidy();

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(219,5): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::~vector' requested here
QFileSystemModelPrivate() = default;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,20): note: in defaulted default constructor for 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' first required here
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,7): note: due to 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' being dllexported
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiexports.h(47,26): note: expanded from macro 'Q_GUI_EXPORT'

## define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h(101,36): note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_EXPORT'

## define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstringalgorithms.h(73,7): note: forward declaration of 'QRegularExpression'
class QRegularExpression;

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/qtguiglobal_p.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui\6.3.0\QtGui/private/../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal_p.h:54:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qtguiglobal.h:43:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:1454:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qtypeinfo.h:43:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\variant:19:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(827,46): error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'QRegularExpression'
_Deallocate<_New_alignof<_Ty>>(_Ptr, sizeof(_Ty) * _Count);
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1621,17): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::allocator::deallocate' requested here
_Al.deallocate(_Myfirst, static_cast<size_type>(_Myend - _Myfirst));

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(593,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Tidy' requested here
_Tidy();

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(219,5): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::~vector' requested here
QFileSystemModelPrivate() = default;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,20): note: in defaulted default constructor for 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' first required here
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,7): note: due to 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' being dllexported
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiexports.h(47,26): note: expanded from macro 'Q_GUI_EXPORT'

## define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h(101,36): note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_EXPORT'

## define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstringalgorithms.h(73,7): note: forward declaration of 'QRegularExpression'
class QRegularExpression;

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:55:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qabstractitemmodel.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qhash.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhash.h:45:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhashfunctions.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qstring.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.h:50:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qchar.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qchar.h:45:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\functional:18:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\unordered_map:11:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xhash:16:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1621,68): error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'std::_Default_allocator_traitsstd::allocator<QRegularExpression>::value_type' (aka 'QRegularExpression')
_Al.deallocate(_Myfirst, static_cast<size_type>(_Myend - _Myfirst));
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(593,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Tidy' requested here
_Tidy();
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(219,5): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::~vector' requested here
QFileSystemModelPrivate() = default;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,20): note: in defaulted default constructor for 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' first required here
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h(94,7): note: due to 'QFileSystemModelPrivate' being dllexported
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QFileSystemModelPrivate : public QAbstractItemModelPrivate

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtGui/qtguiexports.h(47,26): note: expanded from macro 'Q_GUI_EXPORT'

## define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h(101,36): note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECL_EXPORT'

## define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstringalgorithms.h(73,7): note: forward declaration of 'QRegularExpression'
class QRegularExpression;

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp(2072,26): error: out-of-line declaration of a member must be a definition [-Wout-of-line-declaration]
QFileSystemModelPrivate::~QFileSystemModelPrivate(){};
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp(2072,26): error: initializer on function does not look like a pure-specifier
QFileSystemModelPrivate::~QFileSystemModelPrivate(){};
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:55:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qabstractitemmodel.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qhash.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhash.h:45:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhashfunctions.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qstring.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.h:50:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qchar.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qchar.h:45:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\functional:18:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\unordered_map:11:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xhash:16:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1352,9): error: no matching function for call to '_Destroy_range'
_Destroy_range(_Myfirst, _Mylast, _Getal());
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp(2176,24): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::clear' requested here
nameFiltersRegexps.clear();
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(935,19): note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Alloc = std::allocator]
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _First, const _Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _Last, _Alloc& _Al) noexcept {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(946,19): note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_NoThrowFwdIt _First, const _NoThrowSentinel _Last) noexcept {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(1647,9): error: no matching function for call to '_Destroy_range'
_Destroy_range(_First, _Last, _Al);
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(1747,39): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Uninitialized_backout_alstd::allocator<QRegularExpression>::~_Uninitialized_backout_al' requested here
_Uninitialized_backout_al<_Alloc> _Backout{_Dest, _Al};

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1203,13): note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Uninitialized_move<QRegularExpression *, std::allocator>' requested here
_Uninitialized_move(_Myfirst, _Mylast, _Newvec, _Al);

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1273,13): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Reallocate_exactly' requested here
_Reallocate_exactly(_Newcapacity);

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp(2177,24): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::reserve' requested here
nameFiltersRegexps.reserve(nameFilters.size());

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(935,19): note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Alloc = std::allocator]
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _First, const _Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _Last, _Alloc& _Al) noexcept {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(946,19): note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_NoThrowFwdIt _First, const _NoThrowSentinel _Last) noexcept {

from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp:40:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel_p.h:55:
from C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels/qfilesystemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qabstractitemmodel.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qhash.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhash.h:45:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhashfunctions.h:44:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore\qstring.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.h:50:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/qchar.h:1:
from C:\Qt\Qt6.3.0_20\qtbase\include\QtCore/../../../../qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qchar.h:45:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\functional:18:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\unordered_map:11:
from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xhash:16:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1601,13): error: no matching function for call to '_Destroy_range'
_Destroy_range(_Myfirst, _Mylast, _Al);
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1212,9): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Change_array' requested here
_Change_array(_Newvec, _Size, _Newcapacity);

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\vector(1273,13): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::_Reallocate_exactly' requested here
_Reallocate_exactly(_Newcapacity);

C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.3.0\qtbase\src\gui\itemmodels\qfilesystemmodel.cpp(2177,24): note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector::reserve' requested here
nameFiltersRegexps.reserve(nameFilters.size());

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(935,19): note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Alloc = std::allocator]
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _First, const _Alloc_ptr_t<_Alloc> _Last, _Alloc& _Al) noexcept {

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\xmemory(946,19): note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
_CONSTEXPR20 void _Destroy_range(_NoThrowFwdIt _First, const _NoThrowSentinel _Last) noexcept {

11 errors generated.
[38/7776] Automatic MOC for target LanguageServerPrivate
[39/7776] Building CXX object qtdeclarative\src\qmltyperegistrar\CMakeFiles\qmltyperegistrar.dir__\qmlcompiler\qqmljsstreamwriter.cpp.obj
[40/7776] Building CXX object qtdeclarative\src\qmltyperegistrar\CMakeFiles\qmltyperegistrar.dir\qmltypescreator.cpp.obj
[41/7776] Building CXX object qtdeclarative\src\qmltyperegistrar\CMakeFiles\qmltyperegistrar.dir\metatypesjsonprocessor.cpp.obj
[42/7776] Building CXX object qtdeclarative\src\qmltyperegistrar\CMakeFiles\qmltyperegistrar.dir\qmltypesclassdescription.cpp.obj

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The latest patch set 4 provided by Qt had the code-fu needed to calm the compiler.